# Move site page from one module/feature to another and redeploy

Tags: deployment, sitepages

I have a site page that was being deployed within a module that was initially part of one project. I deployed via wsp to my development server and everything was good.

During development I refactored it and moved the page to a different module within a separate project, updated the page and redeployed the wsp to the development server.

Unfortunately for some reason the updated page is not being deployed on development, but instead ignored.  I think this is due to the original page being deployed as part of a different feature/module at first and then the same page being moved to a different feature/module.

When I deploy to production the new version of the page gets deployed each time, I believe this is due to the fact that the page was only ever deployed in one feature/module on production.

Has anyone seen this where SP does not deploy a page when it gets moved from one feature/module to another?

Here's what I have in my elements file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="SitePages" Url="SitePages">
        <File Path="SitePages\PASSHome.aspx" Url="PASSHome.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" ReplaceContent="TRUE" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" />
        <File Path="SitePages\WorkflowStats.aspx" Url="WorkflowStats.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" ReplaceContent="TRUE" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" />
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding `ReplaceContent="True"` to your module XML? Maybe the problem lies in SharePoint ignoring the file as it already exists in the targeted folder.

Comment: I do have that in my module XML, along with IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE"

Comment: Sorry I meant IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE"

Answer (score 1):

Deactivate your features and delete the pages. Reactivate the features and they'll be provisioned again.

My rule of thumb was if I was deploying assets, I had feature deactivation code to delete them. This made rapid development deployment possible by right clicking deploy in VS. The feature would retract, delete the deployed assets, be removed form the farm, reinstalled and then activated, thus deploying my updated assets.